# how to join tables and defined more conditions in mysql

Tags: mysql

I have two tables: `courses` and `courses_partners`. In my `courses` table I have attributes of each course. In `courses_partners` there are only two attributes:

```
course_id(foreign key to courses table)
partner_id(foreign key to partners table).
```

I want to select all `courses`, on which are joined exactly 8 partners(where num rows in `courses_partners` for one `course_id` is 8 (8 is number readed from `courses.maxAmount` attribute)). How to do it? I have something like this, but this not working:

```
SELECT courses_partners.course_id, courses.title, courses.maxAmount FROM 
courses_partners RIGHT JOIN courses ON 
(courses_partners.course_id=courses.course_id) GROUP BY
courses_partners.course_id HAVING COUNT(*) < courses.maxAmount
```

Comment: Sample data would clarify what you are trying to do.

Comment: If there are more than 8 partners for a given course, how should MySQL determine which 8 you wish to be returned?

Comment: I have in courses table for example row with attributes course_id = 7 and maxAmonut = 8 .... When I have in courses_partners less than 8 rows where course_id=7 this course will be returned.

Comment: I'm not sure why you are using a right join. If you have more or equal course.maxAmount partner entries, this won't return anything.

Comment: You state *on which are joined exactly 8 partners* ... do you want *exactly 8* or *less than 8*?

Comment: I want to use : HAVING COUNT(*) < c.maxAmount (like it is on example below(1. answer)) but this return only courses, which has 1,2,3,4,5,6 or 7 (when c.maxAmount is 8)rows in courses_partners , but I want also return courses when there is no rows (0) in courses_partners

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use:

```
SELECT *
FROM courses AS c
WHERE course_id IN (SELECT course_id
                    FROM courses_partners                    
                    GROUP BY course_id
                    HAVING COUNT(*) < c.maxAmount)
```

This will select all courses having *less than* `maxAmount` references to `courses_partners` table.

If you want those references to contain *less than* `maxAmount` records with *distinct* partner_id, then use this `HAVING` clause instead:

```
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT partner_id) < c.maxAmount
```

[**Demo here**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/f135e/1)

Alternatively you can use a `LEFT JOIN`:

```
SELECT c.*
FROM courses AS c
LEFT JOIN (
  SELECT course_id, COUNT(*) AS cnt
  FROM courses_partners                    
  GROUP BY course_id
) AS cp ON c.course_id = cp.course_id AND
           c.maxAmount < cp.cnt
```

This will also return `courses` having no referencing records in `courses_partners` at all.

[**Demo here**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/74cf92/1)

Comment: thanks this work. However, when I have no rows for the certain course in courses_partners?

Comment: @user5503823 Then the row of this course will not be returned. This matches your requirement of returning only courses having `maxAmount` references to `courses_partners`. Do you want something else?

Comment: I want to use : HAVING COUNT(*) < c.maxAmount (like it is on example above) but this return only courses, which has 1,2,3,4,5,6 or 7 (when c.maxAmount is 8)rows in courses_partners , but I want also return courses when there is no rows (0) in courses_partners